# How do I auth to Youtube with angularfire2 FirebaseAuth Google login?

Tags: youtube-api, ionic3, angularfire2, google-oauth

In my Angular 5 / Ionic 3 project, I have Google authentication setup through firebaseauth, and it is working great. **Is there a simple way for me to use that authentication to also access subscription videos in my Youtube account?** I'm trying to avoid using the gapi youtube api, and just send auth data with my youtube request.

```
constructor(public http: HttpClient, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken().then(token => this.token = token);
}

getSubscribedVideos() {
    return this.http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?key=' + this.apiKey 
            + '&mine=true&part=snippet,id&maxResults=20',
            { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token} })})
        .map(data => data['items']);
}
```

I am getting a **401 "Invalid Credentials"** back from the Youtube api. What other data or headers or parameters do I need to send to the youtube api endpoint to authorize the request?

From my package.json:

```
"@angular/core": "5.2.11",
"ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.11",
"firebase": "^5.4.0",
"rxjs": "5.5.11",
```

I've also tried dropping the apiKey, since the youtube doc says it's not required when you pass the OAuth2 token. But I get the same result.

I'm using my Google OAuth2 web client ID. I added `http://localhost:8100` to the Authorized Javascript Origins.

```
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly');
await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
    .then(() => this.nav.setRoot(HomePage));
```

Comment: There are several ways you can implement Oauth for Youtube namely: [server-side flow](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps), [client-side flow](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps), [installed application flow](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps).